# facing an issue with Firebase when offline. Getting "FirebaseError: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config."

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, offline

I've been working on integrating Firebase into my app using the **`useFireBaseAuth`** hook. Everything is smooth when there's an internet connection, but I'm encountering an issue when offline.

The error message is:

> Server Error
>
> FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already
> exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).

I suspect it has something to do with the Firebase initialization in my hook. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
if (firebaseConfig) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  authInstance = getAuth(app);
}
```

Is there a way to handle Firebase initialization more gracefully when there's no internet connection? I want to avoid this duplicate app error. Any guidance on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I tried adding a conditional check before initializing the Firebase app to prevent it from being initialized again if it already exists. Specifically, I added the following code:

```
if (!app) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  authInstance = getAuth(app);
}
```

I was expecting that this conditional check would ensure that the Firebase app is only initialized if it doesn't exist yet. My goal was to address the "FirebaseError: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config" issue when the app is offline. However, it seems that the error still persists. Any insights on how to handle Firebase initialization more effectively in offline scenarios would be appreciated.

```
 const useFireBaseAuth = ({ firebaseConfig }: UseFireBaseAuthProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<auth.User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let app: any;
  let authInstance: auth.Auth;
  const toast = useToast();

  if (firebaseConfig) {
    app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    authInstance = getAuth(app);
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut(authInstance).then((res) => {
      router.push("/");
    });
  };

  const authStateChangeHandler = (authState: any) => {
    if (!authState) {
      setAuthUser(null);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setAuthUser(authState);

      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = authInstance.onAuthStateChanged(authStateChangeHandler);

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    user: authUser,
    loading,
    logOut: handleLogout,
  };
};
```

Comment: This likely doesn't have anything to do with being offline.  You're supposed to call initializeFirebase for the default app only once per process or page load.  Could it be that you're calling it multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should call `initializeApp` outside of your component as you are most likely going to need to call this on every page in your app just to handle authentication. With your current logic, you would be checking if the application was initialized on every single render.

```
// ./services/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

// TODO: load Firebase config

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

In your `useFirebaseAuth` hook, you would optionally pass in the parent `app` object instead. Depending on use case, it might be more appropriate to pass in the instance of `FirebaseAuth` instead of `FirebaseApp`.

```
export default useFirebaseAuth = (app?: FirebaseApp) => {
  const authInstance = getAuth(app);

  // ... rest of code
}
```

If you were trying to prevent calling `initializeApp` twice, you would want to check whether the default app exists or not first.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";

// TODO: load Firebase config

if (getApps().length === 0) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

If your app deals with multiple configurations, you will need to check if the desired app name has been initialized:

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";

const APPCONFIGNAME_A = "appA";

// TODO: load Firebase config for app A

if (!getApps().some((app) => app.name === APPCONFIGNAME_A)) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfigAppA, APPCONFIGNAME_A);
}

// get the initialized app
const appA = getApp(APPCONFIGNAME_A);
```